# PGP with empty passphrase fails in Mule

Tags: encryption, mule, public-key-encryption, pgp

I'm trying to create an encryption-decryption service in Mule using PGP. As I created my key pair without a passphrase (since this is just a proof of concept), naturally I am not setting it in my config. However it seems Mule is enforcing a non-empty passphrase.

The error I'm getting:

```
    ERROR 2015-02-23 14:19:31,509 [[mule-pgp].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Crypto Failure
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-111
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. The password should not be null (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
  org.apache.commons.lang.Validate:203 (null)
2. Crypto Failure (org.mule.api.security.CryptoFailureException)
  org.mule.module.pgp.KeyBasedEncryptionStrategy:75 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/security/CryptoFailureException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The password should not be null
    at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:203)
    at org.mule.module.pgp.DecryptStreamTransformer.<init>(DecryptStreamTransformer.java:56)
    at org.mule.module.pgp.KeyBasedEncryptionStrategy.decrypt(KeyBasedEncryptionStrategy.java:69)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Is there any way to get around this? I tried setting a space for the passphrase but no cigar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/bfb3a17263d1e4b32ee10272cbf710a2bf41b16b/modules/pgp/src/main/java/org/mule/module/pgp/DecryptStreamTransformer.java#L53-57) shows a bunch of validations that can't be bypassed:

```
Validate.notNull(toBeDecrypted, "The toBeDecrypted should not be null");
Validate.notNull(publicKey, "The publicKey should not be null");
Validate.notNull(secretKey, "The secretKey should not be null");
Validate.notNull(password, "The password should not be null");
Validate.notNull(provider, "The security provider can't be null");
```

So the only workaround for your problem I can think of is to actually use a passphrase.

Comment: Got it. Bit of a bummer though, I understand the security aspect of things but I don't like a tool pretty much forcing me to use one feature or other. It's like saying you can only use 2048 bit keys or higher, no matter what your circumstances.